# Does MongoDB track how many times each index is used in a query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with 20+ indexes and I'm not sure which ones are actually being used on a regular basis. I suspect that a couple of very large indexes are used very infrequently but are negatively impacting write performance and memory usage. Does mmap or WiredTiger keep stats on how many times each index is used to return results?

Update: I found https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2227 which seems to indicate that this should exist in version 3.2+ but couldn't find any docs on actually viewing this counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$indexStats](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/) (new in version 3.2):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $indexStats: { } }])
```

Which, besides other information, returns the *number of operations that used the index* (ops property).

```
{
    "name" : "_id_",
    "key" : { "_id" : 1 },
    "host" : "test-dev:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(2),
        "since" : ISODate("2016-04-21T14:15:57.846Z") 
    } 
}
```